# Delete images from folder which are not found in Table using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, webforms

I upload blog related image in one of the folder and some of the images related to blog where where updated where not actually deleted from the folder, so over several years we have some images which are not used for blog and take space.

So i thought i writting code which will compare all the images in `blog` folder with blog table column and delete all image which are not found in table. I store 1 image by default in Blog Table and multiple images related to blog in different table for this reason i cam using Union to get all images that are used for blogs.

problem with the below code is that it hangs, not sure how to optiomize it or delete the unwanted images which are no longer used for blog

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT ID AS ID, ImageName AS Image FROM [Blog]";
        sqlQuery += " UNION " ;
        sqlQuery += " SELECT ImageID AS ID, ImageName AS Image FROM [BlogGallery_Images] ";
        ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(sqlQuery);
        int rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        string strPhysicalFolder = Server.MapPath("../images/BlogImages/");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(strPhysicalFolder);

 bool ImageFound = false;

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(info.FullName);

            //Response.Write("File : " + fileName.ToLower());

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                string dbfileName = dr["Image"].ToString();

                if (dbfileName == fileName)
                {
                     //Response.Write(" -- FILE FOUND <br>");
                    ImageFound = true;
                }
                else
                {
                     //Response.Write(" -- FILE NOT FOUND <br>");
                    ImageFound = false;
                }
            }


            if (ImageFound == false)
            {
                //dont delete image
            }
            else
            {
                //logic to delete image
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Where does your program hang?

Comment: Also in your inner loop, you are not escaping out of the loop when dbfileName == fileName. Thus, if dbFileName does not equal fileName in the next iteration, ImageFound will be reset to false even though it has been previously found. Also, `bool ImageFound = false` should be defined within your first foreach loop, not outside of it as it should be reset to false for each file you are checking.

Comment: Is there any exception thrown? Maybe the application does't have enough access rights to delete files from the server?

Comment: Its in the second loop`foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)` it takes ages & slows down computer....This happens when i only have 2000 records in database with bigger database it might get even slower, is there i can do to improve the performance..

Comment: Try a quick and dirty timing test just looping through the filenames and table rows to get a rate in things-per-second. Since the inner loop is repeated for each pass through the outer loop you want to have the cheaper (aka faster) loop on the inside.)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your bottleneck is `foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)`

You could try extracting this out out by looping through your data rows once and reading the filenames into a HashSet. A HashSet is optimized for quickly finding values.

Then, when you loop through each file, you can check if the HashSet contains the file name.

```
var fileNamesInDb = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string dbfileName = dr["Image"].ToString();
    fileNamesInDb.Add(dbfileName);
}


foreach (string file in files)
{   
    System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(info.FullName);

    //Response.Write("File : " + fileName.ToLower());

    if (fileNamesInDb.Contains(fileName))
    {
        //dont delete image
    }
    else
    {
        //logic to delete image
    }
}
```